# ASP Classic code returning true instead of response.write result

Tags: html, asp-classic

I have a piece of ASP Classic code that instead of response writing my information it returns "true"

Here is the relevant line:

```
response.write "<a href='search.htm?supplier_name= & request.querystring('supplier_name') & "&aircraft_type=" & request.querystring('aircraft_type') & "&state=" & request.querystring('state') & "&order=state'>State</a>"
```

I believe the problem is associated with this section:

```
& "&order=state'>State</a>"
```

The ASP code in full:

```
<%
if request.querystring("order") = "state" then 
response.write("State")
else
response.write "<a href='search.htm?supplier_name= & request.querystring('supplier_name') & "&aircraft_type=" & request.querystring('aircraft_type') & "&state=" & request.querystring('state') & "&order=state'>State</a>"
end if
%>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Missing a double quote after `supplier_name=`:

```
response.write "<a href='search.htm?supplier_name=" & request.querystring('supplier_name') & "&aircraft_type=" & request.querystring('aircraft_type') & "&state=" & request.querystring('state') & "&order=state'>State</a>"
```